# Locking a variable cell in an excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

This is an apparently simple question, I have this formula in my macro

```
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+RC[-1]*RC[-12" & "]/**R[-1]C14*R[-1]C15**/RC[-11]"
```

The strong part is what I need to lock like this ie.:

```
 =Y56*N56/$N$55*$O$55/O56
```

but when I run the macro appears like this

```
 =Y56*N56/$N55*$O55/O56
```

Answer (score 0):

When using R1C1 notation it will interpret it like this

`R[-1]C15` the [-1] is relative to the ActiveCell so when you see it on the sheet it will be a relative reference. It will appear without the $. This should be expected because you are asking for a cell one row above the active one. This is certainly a relative reference, not an absolute one.

If you want to force an absolute reference you need to specify the row you want like this `R12C15`. Or you can avoid using R1C1 notation and simply string together in the code the references you want. As in: `=Y56*N56/$N$55*$O$55/O56`

Comment: If this answer is helpful please click the checkmark on the left. Also if you like you can up vote it.